# mac os monterey - cannot insert emoji icon

Tags: macos

I have a new macbook air m1 running macOS Monterey v12.5. I click ctrl+cmd+space and it presents emojis but when I click one it does not insert anything? This is regardless of the software I'm trying to insert into - I've tried several including the mac Notes app and Microsoft Word.

Anyone solved this?

Comment: It's double-click. 

Comment: Thanks @Tetsujin double-click works.